# Non-empty buckets in LSH

Tags: locality-sensitive-hash

I'm reading this survey about [LSH](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.2927), in particular citing the last paragraph of section `2.2.1`:

> To improve the recall, L hash tables are constructed, and the items
>   lying in the L (L ′ , L ′ < L) hash buckets h_1 (q), · · · , h_L (q)
>   are retrieved as near items of q for randomized R-near neighbor search
>   (or randomized c- approximate R-near neighbor search).
>   To guarantee the precision, each of the L hash codes, y_i , needs to
>   be a long code, which means that the total number of the buckets is
>   too large to index directly. **Thus, only the nonempty buckets are
>   retained by resorting to convectional hashing of the hash codes h_l
>   (x).**

I have 3 questions:

1. The bold sentence is not clear to me: what does it mean by "resorting to convenctional hashing of the hash codes `h_l (x)`"?
2. Always about the bold sentence, I'm not sure that I got the problem: I totally understand that `h_l(x)` can be a long code and so the number of possible buckets can be huge. For example, if `h_l(x)` is a binary code and `length` is `h_l(x)`'s length, then we have in total `L*2^length` possible buckets (since we use `L` hash tables)...is that correct?
3. Last question: once we find which bucket the query vector `q` belongs to, in order to find the nearest neighbor we have to use the original vector `q` and the original distance metric? For example, let suppose that the original vector `q` is in 128 dimensions `q=[1,0,12,...,14.3]^T` and it uses the euclidean distance in our application. Now suppose that our hashing function (supposing that L=1 for simplicity) used in LSH maps this vector to a binary space in 20 dimensions `y=[0100...11]^T` in order to decide which bucket assign `q` to. So `y` has the same index of the bucket `B`, and which already contains 100 vectors. Now, in order to find the nearest neighbor, we have to compare `q` with all the others 100 128-dimensions vectors using euclidean distance. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Approach they are using to improve recall constructs more hash tables and essentially stores multiple copies of the ID for each reference item, hence space cost is larger [4]. If there are a lot of empty buckets which increases the retrieval cost, the double-hash scheme or fast search algorithm in the Hamming space can be used to fast retrieve the hash buckets. I think in this case they are using double hash function to retrieve non-empty buckets.

No of buckets/memory cells [1][2][3] -> O(nL)

References:

[1] http://simsearch.yury.name/russir/03nncourse-hand.pdf

[2] http://joyceho.github.io/cs584_s16/slides/lsh-12.pdf

[3] https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~niejiazhong/slides/kumar.pdf

[4] http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/jingdw/Pubs%5CLTHSurvey.pdf